# Show/Hide tbody tag inside table

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have an html table with 2 tbody's that I'm trying to show/hide based on specific value that been selected in drop down.

The issue is when I'm using JS to hide the first tbody and show the second tbody it's been minimized like in the attached picture.

**First tbody**

[image]

**second tbody**

[image]

```html
            <table class="timecardinfotable">
                <colgroup>
                    <col style="width:95px" />
                </colgroup>

                <tbody>
               
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Work Dept.:
                    </td>
                        <td>
                             <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbWorkDept" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LocationPostName") %>' DataTextField="LocationPostName"  EmptyMessage="Select Work Department"  Width="240px" AutoPostBack="True" MarkFirstMatch="True"  AllowCustomText="true" EnableTextSelection="true" ></telerik:RadComboBox>
                             <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtWordDepID" runat="server"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EmployeeLocationID") %>' Width="240px" Visible="false"></telerik:RadTextBox> 
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Employee #:
                    </td>
                        <td>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbEmployees" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EmployeeNameAndNumber") %>' EmptyMessage="Select Employee"  Width="240px" AutoPostBack="False" MarkFirstMatch="True"  AllowCustomText="true" EnableTextSelection="true"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtEmployeeNumber" runat="server"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EmployeeNumber") %>' Width="240px" Visible="false"></telerik:RadTextBox> 
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Category:
                    </td>
                     <td>
                         <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbTransactionCategory" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AttendanceTransactionCategory") %>' DataTextField="AttendanceTransactionCategory"  EmptyMessage="Select Category"  Width="240px" AutoPostBack="False" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="HideOptions"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                     </td>
                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

                <tbody id="tbodytransactions" runat="server" class="bodytransactions">
               
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                        Clock In:
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2"> 
                       <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtpClockIn" runat="server" DbSelectedDate='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ClockInDateTime") %>' Width="192px">
                             <Calendar ID="calanderClockIn" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="True">
                                <SpecialDays>
                                    <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" Date="" ItemStyle-BackColor="lightblue"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                                 </SpecialDays>
                             </Calendar> 
                            <DateInput ID="diClockIn" ToolTip="ClockIn Date input" runat="server"/>   
                       </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>

                       <asp:HiddenField ID="hfClockInID" Value='<%# Eval("ClockInID") %>' runat="server"  />

                       <telerik:RadButton ID="rbClockInPictureComments" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="22px" Width="22px" ToolTip="Clock In - Picture and Comments" Enabled="True" CommandName="GetClockInPictureComments">
                          <Icon PrimaryIconUrl="../../Images/Icons/TransactionInfo.png" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"></Icon>
                       </telerik:RadButton>

                       <telerik:RadButton ID="rbClockInAdjusmentReason" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Height="22px" Width="22px" ToolTip="Clock In - Reason For Adjusment" Enabled="True" OnClientClicked="ClockInReasonForAdjustment">
                          <Icon PrimaryIconUrl="../../Images/Icons/AdjustmentReason.png" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"></Icon>
                       </telerik:RadButton>
                       <div id="divclockinreason" runat="server" class="clockinreason">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtClockInAdjusmentReason" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Width="242px" MaxLength="100" EmptyMessage="Clock In - Reason For Adjusment"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ClockInReasonForAdjustment") %>'></telerik:RadTextBox> 
                       </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                        Start Break:
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2"> 
                        <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtpStartBreak" runat="server" DbSelectedDate='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.StartBreakDateTime") %>' Width="192px">
                        <Calendar ID="calanderStartBreak" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="True">
                                <SpecialDays>
                                    <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" Date="" ItemStyle-BackColor="lightblue"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                                 </SpecialDays>
                             </Calendar> 
                            <DateInput ID="diStartBreak" ToolTip="Start Break Date input" runat="server"/>   
                        </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfStartBreakID" Value='<%# Eval("StartBreakID") %>' runat="server"  />     
                        
                       <telerik:RadButton ID="rbStartBreakPictureComments" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="22px" Width="22px" ToolTip="Start Break - Picture and Comments" Enabled="True" CommandName="GetStartBreakPictureComments">
                          <Icon PrimaryIconUrl="../../Images/Icons/TransactionInfo.png" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"></Icon>
                       </telerik:RadButton>

                       <telerik:RadButton ID="rbStartBreakAdjusmentReason" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Height="22px" Width="22px" ToolTip="Start Break - Reason For Adjusment" Enabled="True" OnClientClicked="StartBreakReasonForAdjustment">
                          <Icon PrimaryIconUrl="../../Images/Icons/AdjustmentReason.png" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"></Icon>
                       </telerik:RadButton>

                      <div id="divstartbreakreason" runat="server" class="startbreakreason">
                         <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtStartBreakAdjusmentReason"  runat="server" Width="242px" MaxLength="100" EmptyMessage="Start Break - Reason For Adjusment" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.StartBreakReasonForAdjustment") %>'></telerik:RadTextBox>
                       </div>                                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                        End Break:
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2"> 
                        <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtpEndBreak" runat="server" DbSelectedDate='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EndBreakDateTime") %>' Width="192px">
                         <Calendar ID="calanderEndBreak" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="True">
                            <SpecialDays>
                              <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" Date="" ItemStyle-BackColor="lightblue"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                            </SpecialDays>
                          </Calendar> 
                         <DateInput ID="diEndBreak" ToolTip="End Break Date input" runat="server"/>   
                        </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfEndBreakID" Value='<%# Eval("EndBreakID") %>' runat="server"  /> 
                        
                         <telerik:RadButton ID="rbEndBreakPictureComments" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="22px" Width="22px" ToolTip="End Break - Picture and Comments" Enabled="True" CommandName="GetEndBreakPictureComments">
                             <Icon PrimaryIconUrl="../../Images/Icons/TransactionInfo.png" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"></Icon>
                         </telerik:RadButton>
                         
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="rbEndBreakAdjusmentReason" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Height="22px" Width="22px" ToolTip="End Break - Reason For Adjusment" Enabled="True" OnClientClicked="EndBreakReasonForAdjustment">
                          <Icon PrimaryIconUrl="../../Images/Icons/AdjustmentReason.png" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"></Icon>
                       </telerik:RadButton>

                       <div id="divendbreakreason" runat="server" class="endbreakreason">
                       <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtEndBreakAdjusmentReason"  runat="server" Width="242px" MaxLength="100" EmptyMessage="End Break - Reason For Adjusment" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EndBreakReasonForAdjustment") %>'></telerik:RadTextBox>
                       </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Clock Out:
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2"> 
                        <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtpClockOut" runat="server" DbSelectedDate='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ClockOutDateTime") %>' Width="192px">
                          <Calendar ID="calanderClockOut" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="True">
                            <SpecialDays>
                              <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" Date="" ItemStyle-BackColor="lightblue"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                            </SpecialDays>
                          </Calendar> 
                         <DateInput ID="diClockOut" ToolTip="Clock ut Date input" runat="server"/>  
                        </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfClockOutID" Value='<%# Eval("ClockOutID") %>' runat="server"  /> 
                        
                         <telerik:RadButton ID="rbClockOutPictureComments" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="22px" Width="22px" ToolTip="Clock Out - Picture and Comments" Enabled="True" CommandName="GetClockOutPictureComments">
                             <Icon PrimaryIconUrl="../../Images/Icons/TransactionInfo.png" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"></Icon>
                         </telerik:RadButton>
                         
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="rbClockOutAdjusmentReason" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Height="22px" Width="22px" ToolTip="Clock Out - Reason For Adjusment" Enabled="True" OnClientClicked="ClockOutReasonForAdjustment">
                          <Icon PrimaryIconUrl="../../Images/Icons/AdjustmentReason.png" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"></Icon>
                       </telerik:RadButton>
                       <div id="divclockoutreason" runat="server" class="clockoutreason"> 
                          <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtClockOutAdjusmentReason"  runat="server" Width="242px" MaxLength="100" EmptyMessage="Clock Out - Reason For Adjusment" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ClockOutReasonForAdjustment") %>'></telerik:RadTextBox>        
                      </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

                <tbody id="tbodycategorized" runat="server" class="bodycategorized" style="border:1px solid red">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Work Day:
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpWorkDay" runat="server" Width="120px" AutoPostBack="false">
                             <Calendar ID="fromCalendar" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="True">
                                <SpecialDays>
                                    <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" Date="" ItemStyle-BackColor="lightblue"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                                 </SpecialDays>
                             </Calendar> 
                            <DateInput ID="diWorkDay" ToolTip="From Date input" runat="server"/>      
                           </telerik:RadDatePicker>  
                           <telerik:RadTimePicker ID="rtpWorkTime" runat="server" DateInput-DateFormat="HH:mm" TimeView-TimeFormat="HH:mm" Width="90px"></telerik:RadTimePicker>

                        </td>
                       
                    </tr>
                
                </tbody>

            </table>





<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
        function HideOptions(sender,eventArgs) {
            var item = eventArgs.get_item();
            var ClockIn = $find("<%=rdtpClockIn.ClientID %>");
            var ClockOut = $find("<%=rdtpClockOut.ClientID %>");
            var StartBreak = $find("<%=rdtpStartBreak.ClientID %>");
            var EndBreak = $find("<%=rdtpEndBreak.ClientID %>");
            var tbodytransactions = document.getElementById("<%=tbodytransactions.ClientID%>");
            var tbodycategorized = document.getElementById("<%=tbodycategorized.ClientID%>");
             if (item.get_text() === "Sick") {
                 //Hide all the options.
                 tbodytransactions.style.display = "none";
                 tbodycategorized.style.display = "block";
             } else if (item.get_text() === "Regular") {
                 tbodytransactions.style.display = "block";
                 tbodycategorized.style.display = "none";
             }
         }
```

Comment: try: tbodycategorized.style.visibility = "hidden";

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but set `ClientIDMode=Static` for the HTML elements you're accessing with `$find`. This allows you to use the `ID` that you assigned the element, instead of having to use `("<%=tbodytransactions.ClientID%>");`

Comment: Rana* using visibility hidden is creating a huge space between the first tbody to the second tbody

Comment: @MarkZu May be problem with CSS?  Add CSS code for "bodycategorized" and "bodytransactions" classes

Comment: .bodytransactions
   {
      display: block;
     
      

   }
   
   .bodycategorized
   {
      display: none;

   }

Answer (score 0):

create separated divs for each part of the tbody and stilish with display:none

**pseudo:**

```
function select(){
    if(dropDown select 1) {
        document.getElementById(div1).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(div2).style.display = 'block';
    } else if(dropDown select 2) {
        document.getElementById(div1).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById(div2).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that I can create a div inside of a tbody? I created the tbody in order to avoid using nasted div's inside of a table.

Comment: i think the point is, you want to show an element contained in a table but i think that's not the optimal way... because the table should be there to create the space, not to shows up or shows down, in that case you should Add a new Row in the table...

you must encapsulate what you want to show:
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div1> <- show this
                <div2> <- or this